# Haskell finding mean of cubes of odd members Any ideas?

Tags: list, haskell, mean, cubes

Please find the mean of cubes of odd members of given list of Int type.

Try to use  (.), ($), map, filter or foldl (You should use at least one of them).

Comment: Can you let us know what you have tried ? It would be useful to see from your errors where you are stuck up and proceed from there.

Comment: This readily seperates to subproblems: mean of a list, cube all numbers in a list, extract the odd numbers in a list. Surely you can do at least _one_ of these?

Comment: Looks like homework...

Comment: Are homeworks not allowed? I don't really understand what's the problem? I asked a question, and I thought that's what this site is about, I suppose it's easier to judge that I can not do it on my own. I'm afraid that's not very helpful and it's plainly rude. Cheers.

Comment: Well, it certainly would not be helpful if we simply gave you a full copy-and-paste solution that you don't really understand. To properly help you, we need to know what you already know and where you have problems. Before calling the community rude you should think a moment why people are bothering to reply at all...

Comment: that is what i said, I find nothing useful in pointig out the fact that this is my homework. I honestly don't find any reasons why people respond, when they have no intentions to comment with something useful. I called the comment rude, I was not aware I hurt your feelings too. Sorry. :)

Comment: @user3706898: We're all volunteers here, and as a community, we have decided that we don't do people's homework for them unless they have shown some effort.  You have not reached that minimal level.  If you want help, show us what you have tried.

Comment: @user3706898: And, by the way, I want to clarify that we would be **happy** to help you, once you have reached that **very** minimal level of effort required.  We want to see evidence that you have tried this yourself.  We're not here to help you cheat.

Comment: @user3706898 I am sorry but I agree with nomen's comments. The sad thing is you just copy-pasted the problem. Even a "I think I should start with filtering out the even numbers" would make me write a proper answer, but it's obvious that you just want to get a good grade in your homework.

Comment: whatever man, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I would give you some hints to get you started up:

1. Use `filter` function to get the odd members of the given list.
2. Cube the resultant list using `map` function.
3. Find the mean of them by summing the list and dividing it by the length of the list.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I would add to the other comments and answers is the use of `fromIntegral` to convert the `Int` type to `Fractional` for using the `(/)` operator.